# Add 1 blank column every 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, addition

I have a dataframe "df" like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
 1    2    2    3    5    7
 2    4    6    4    8    2
 5    9    7    3    2    5
 3    4    5    6    8    1
```

and I would like to create a new dataframe "new_df" in which there is 1 blank column (called "empty") every 2 columns, like this:

```
empty col1 col2 empty col3 col4 empty col5 col6
 NA    1    2    NA    2    3    NA    5    7
 NA    2    4    NA    6    4    NA    8    2
 NA    5    9    NA    7    3    NA    2    5
 NA    3    4    NA    5    6    NA    8    1
```

How can I add the blank column in this way?
I have tried using:

```
n = length(df)
empty <- NA

for (i in seq(1,n-2,2))
  {
  new_df <- add_column(df, empty, .before=i)
  }
```

but it memorizes only the last step, giving me this result:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 empty col5 col6
 1    2     2    3   NA    5    7
 2    4     6    4   NA    8    2
 5    9     7    3   NA    2    5
 3    4     5    6   NA    8    1
```

Comment: the reason it only remember the last step is that each time you make new_df you are using the original df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base R solution would be:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by = 2), function(i) cbind(empty = rep(NA, nrow(df)), df[, seq(i, i+1)])))

#  empty col1 col2 empty col3 col4 empty col5 col6
#1    NA    1    2    NA    2    3    NA    5    7
#2    NA    2    4    NA    6    4    NA    8    2
#3    NA    5    9    NA    7    3    NA    2    5
#4    NA    3    4    NA    5    6    NA    8    1
```

A "tidy" solution could be:

```
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(seq(from = 1, to = ncol(df), by = 2),
        ~df %>%
          mutate(empty = NA) %>%
          select(empty, .x, .x+1))

#New names:
#* empty -> empty...1
#* empty -> empty...4
#* empty -> empty...7
#empty...1 col1 col2 empty...4 col3 col4 empty...7 col5 col6
#1        NA    1    2        NA    2    3        NA    5    7
#2        NA    2    4        NA    6    4        NA    8    2
#3        NA    5    9        NA    7    3        NA    2    5
#4        NA    3    4        NA    5    6        NA    8    1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another base R solution

```
tmp1=seq(1,ncol(df),3)
tmp2=!(1:ncol(df) %in% tmp1)

df2=data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow(df),ncol(df)+ncol(df)/2))
df2[tmp2]=df

colnames(df2)[tmp1]=paste0("empty",1:length(tmp1))
colnames(df2)[tmp2]=colnames(df)

  empty1 col1 col2 empty2 col3 col4 empty3 col5 col6
1     NA    1    2     NA    2    3     NA    5    7
2     NA    2    4     NA    6    4     NA    8    2
3     NA    5    9     NA    7    3     NA    2    5
4     NA    3    4     NA    5    6     NA    8    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `append()`.

```
for (i in 0:2*ncol(dat)/2) dat <- as.data.frame(append(dat, list(emp=NA), i))
dat
#   emp col1 col2 emp.1 col3 col4 emp.2 col5 col6
# 1  NA    1    2    NA    2    3    NA    5    7
# 2  NA    2    4    NA    6    4    NA    8    2
# 3  NA    5    9    NA    7    3    NA    2    5
# 4  NA    3    4    NA    5    6    NA    8    1
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), col2 = c(2L, 4L, 9L, 
4L), col3 = c(2L, 6L, 7L, 5L), col4 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 6L), col5 = c(5L, 
8L, 2L, 8L), col6 = c(7L, 2L, 5L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

---

*And here comes the ...*

### Microbenchmark

```
# Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval    cld
#  ronak()  969.707  990.9945 1001.4807 1012.282 1017.368 1022.453     3    d  
#   user()  349.937  358.0145  364.3877  366.092  371.613  377.134     3 a     
#    jay() 2098.003 2100.8540 2115.7640 2103.705 2124.644 2145.584     3     e 
# groth1() 2164.896 2262.5745 2363.6133 2360.253 2462.972 2565.691     3      f
# groth2()  424.546  438.0185  455.0820  451.491  470.350  489.209     3 ab    
# groth3()  722.551  728.0910  733.1910  733.631  738.511  743.391     3   c   
# r.user()  612.432  619.6570  636.9573  626.882  649.220  671.558     3  bc   


## and with the usual expanded data frame:
set.seed(42)
dat <- dat[sample(nrow(dat), 1e6, replace=T), ]
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ronak(), user(), jay(), groth1(), groth2(), groth3(), r.user(), times=3L)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr         min          lq        mean      median         uq        max neval cld
#  ronak() 1375.139030 1456.858743 1564.509886 1538.578457 1659.19531 1779.81217     3   c
#   user()   89.017416  200.845539  251.548652  312.673662  332.81427  352.95488     3 a  
#    jay()    7.655812    8.382333    9.941684    9.108855   11.08462   13.06039     3 a  
# groth1()  501.263785  514.097103  621.755474  526.930421  682.00132  837.07222     3  b 
# groth2()  143.438836  147.783741  189.033391  152.128645  211.83067  271.53269     3 a  
# groth3() 1387.314877 1406.898863 1469.493158 1426.482849 1510.58230 1594.68175     3   c
# r.user() 1469.543881 1472.770464 1483.834022 1475.997046 1490.97909 1505.96114     3   c
```

*Code:*

```
ronak <- \() {
  split_data <- split.default(dat,rep(seq_along(dat), each=2, length.out=ncol(dat)))
  do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) cbind(setNames(data.frame(NA), paste0('empty', x)), y), 
                     seq_along(split_data), split_data))
}

user <- \() {
  tmp1=seq(1, 9,3);tmp2=!(1:9 %in% tmp1);dat2=data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow(dat),ncol(dat)+ncol(dat)/2))
  dat2[tmp2]=dat;colnames(dat2)[tmp1]=paste0("empty",1:length(tmp1))
  colnames(dat2)[tmp2]=colnames(dat);dat2
}

jay <- \() {for (i in 0:2*ncol(dat)/2) dat <- as.data.frame(append(dat, list(emp=NA), i));dat}

groth1 <- \() suppressMessages({
  require(dplyr):require(purrr)
  dat %>% split.default(as.numeric(gl(ncol(.), 2, ncol(.)))) %>% map(~ bind_cols(empty=NA, .)) %>%
    bind_cols
})

groth2 <- \() {
  ix <- cumsum(seq_along(dat) %% 2 + 1);dat2 <- replace(data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow(dat), max(ix))), ix, dat)
  names(dat2) <- replace(rep("empty", ncol(dat2)), ix, names(dat));dat2
}

groth3 <- \() {
  ix <- as.numeric(gl(ncol(dat), 2, ncol(dat)))  # 1 1 2 2 3 3
  do.call("cbind", Map(cbind, empty = NA, split.default(dat, ix)))
}

r.user <- \() do.call(cbind, lapply(seq(1, ncol(dat), by=2), function(i)
  cbind(empty=rep(NA, nrow(dat)), dat[, seq(i, i+1)])))
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I took account for this in an edit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**!) dplyr/purrr** Split the data frame, DF, bind an NA column before each component and bind the resulting components back together.  Using the same column name in multiple columns as in the sample output in the question has the problem that it is not possible to identify columns by name so this uses unique names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

DF %>%
  split.default(as.numeric(gl(ncol(.), 2, ncol(.)))) %>%
  map(~ bind_cols(empty = NA, .)) %>%
  bind_cols
```

giving:

```
  empty...1 col1 col2 empty...4 col3 col4 empty...7 col5 col6
1        NA    1    2        NA    2    3        NA    5    7
2        NA    2    4        NA    6    4        NA    8    2
3        NA    5    9        NA    7    3        NA    2    5
4        NA    3    4        NA    5    6        NA    8    1
```

**2) Base R** Create a vector ix which gives the indexes of the original data frame in the result data frame and then create an empty result and copy DF and its names into it.

```
ix <- cumsum(seq_along(DF) %% 2 + 1)    # 2 3 5 6 8 9
DF2 <- replace(data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow(DF), max(ix))), ix, DF)
names(DF2) <- replace(rep("empty", ncol(DF2)), ix, names(DF))

DF2
```

giving:

```
  empty col1 col2 empty col3 col4 empty col5 col6
1    NA    1    2    NA    2    3    NA    5    7
2    NA    2    4    NA    6    4    NA    8    2
3    NA    5    9    NA    7    3    NA    2    5
4    NA    3    4    NA    5    6    NA    8    1
```

**3) Base R** This is another Base R solution. It roughly translates (1) into Base R.  It gives the same result as (2).

```
ix <- as.numeric(gl(ncol(DF), 2, ncol(DF)))  # 1 1 2 2 3 3
do.call("cbind", Map(cbind, empty = NA, split.default(DF, ix)))
```

**4) eList** The eList package can be used for a particularly short solution.

```
library(eList)

DF(for(i in seq(1, ncol(DF), 2)) list(empty = NA, DF[seq(i, len = 2)]))
```

giving:

```
  empty col1 col2 empty.1 col3 col4 empty.2 col5 col6
1    NA    1    2      NA    2    3      NA    5    7
2    NA    2    4      NA    6    4      NA    8    2
3    NA    5    9      NA    7    3      NA    2    5
4    NA    3    4      NA    5    6      NA    8    1
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form.

```
Lines <- "col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
 1    2    2    3    5    7
 2    4    6    4    8    2
 5    9    7    3    2    5
 3    4    5    6    8    1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I was using 4.0 but there does seem to be a difference in 4.1.  I have changed c(...) to as.numeric(...) and now it should be the same in both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R option -

We can split the data every 2 columns into list of dataframe and use `Map` to add a new column with `NA` in each dataframe.

```
split_data <- split.default(df,rep(seq_along(df), each = 2, length.out = ncol(df)))

do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) 
  cbind(setNames(data.frame(NA), paste0('empty', x)), y), 
  seq_along(split_data), split_data)) -> result

result

#  empty1 col1 col2 empty2 col3 col4 empty3 col5 col6
#1     NA    1    2     NA    2    3     NA    5    7
#2     NA    2    4     NA    6    4     NA    8    2
#3     NA    5    9     NA    7    3     NA    2    5
#4     NA    3    4     NA    5    6     NA    8    1
```

It is not a good practice to have duplicate column names in a dataframe hence I name them as `empty1`, `empty2` etc.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), col2 = c(2L, 4L, 9L, 
4L), col3 = c(2L, 6L, 7L, 5L), col4 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 6L), col5 = c(5L, 
8L, 2L, 8L), col6 = c(7L, 2L, 5L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```